# How to correctly handle relationships between models in blade templates?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create shopping cart page. From controller I'm getting an array of order items.
Order item has foreign key "meal_id" - relationship with table meals. I need to access to connected meal object, to display information. How should I do it correctly? I tried to include php key inside blade template:

```
        @foreach($order_items as $order_item)
                ...
                @php
                    $meal = \App\Models\Meal::where('id', '=', $order_item->meal_id)->get();
                @endphp
                ...
        @endforeach
```

But it doesn't work. Of course I can send two different arrays of order_items and meals and hope, that sequence will be equal...
Or I can somehow send one array with joint tables.
But isn't there more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a relationship between the models so you'll have access to it via the Eloquent ORM and you will be able to do something like that in your blade template for example:

```
$order_item->meals;
```

You can read more about Laravel relationships and how to set each type of relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

you can't intract with database inside view files , this is neither clean code , nor usefull, and it is cause a problem called N+1 problem ,
the solution is to create a relationship inside the model class, you can find more about relationships at laravel.com,
anyway here is an examlpe :
first thing create a method inside the `Order` model named `meals` , then you need to select which relation you should use , in your case the relation is has many , since Meal has many order items , so inside the meal method use like this:
`return $this->belongsTo(Order::class)`.
for more examples I realy recommend you to see Eloquent Relationships on laravel.com
they have a great docs to simplify these things,
after creating the relationship and before passing the `$order_items` to the view, you should load the relation , somthing like this : `Order::with('meal')->get()` or if you already have an instanse you can use `$orders->load('meal')`, ther is several ways how to call a relationship , but however you do it , try to do it outside the view section or any loops insid  blade